# The system cannot find the path specified

Tags: asp-classic, iis-6

Here's the setup...

I'm trying to redirect websiteA.com to websiteB.com

My plan is to use a custom 404.asp page on websiteA.com to 301 redirect to websiteB.com

Here's an excerpt from my 404 page:

```
Response.Status="301 Moved Permanently"
select case lcase(request.servervariables("QUERY_STRING"))
     case "http://redirect.websiteA.com/1234.asp"
          Response.AddHeader "Location","http://www.websiteB.com/1234.aspx"
     case else
          Response.AddHeader "Location","http://www.websiteB.com/"
end select
```

To test my 404 page, I've setup a sub-domain on websiteA.com we'll call it redirect.websiteA.com

I have a default.asp setup on redirect.websiteA.com, and the browser resolves http://redirect.websiteA.com correctly.  But, when the browser tries to resolve http://redirect.websiteA.com/folderThatDoesntExist/ I get the error "The system cannot find the path specified"

I setup 404.asp in the custom errors section of IIS for redirect.websiteA.com

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I got it.  The path I was using for my 404 page required that I setup a Virtual Directory.  Long story short.  The path, to my 404 page, that I was using in Customer Errors, was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Try looking at what you get from the `lcase(request.servervariables("QUERY_STRING"))`, I bet you get somethings like 404; before the url.

In one of my projects i use this ugly code to cleanup the string:

```
  temppath=replace(replace(replace(replace(Request.ServerVariables("QUERY_STRING"),"404;",""),":80",""),":443",""),"//","/")

  strFileName     = mid(temppath,instrrev(temppath,"/")+1,len(temppath))
  temppath= mid(temppath,instrrev(temppath, Request.ServerVariables("SERVER_NAME"))+len(Request.ServerVariables("SERVER_NAME")),len(temppath))
```

Comment: Right now, it's not even getting to my 404 page.  I have a `code`response.write("init") response.end()`code`
at the top of my 404 page and it's not hitting that line before throwing the error.

Comment: You were right, it was adding 404; and 80: to the URL.  I did have to replace those.  But, that wasn't causing the error.  Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

In IIS you could change the sites directory to a **redirection to a URL**.
Type in the URL and specify other options like
 1. The exact URl entered above
 2. A directory below the URL entered
 3. A permanent redirection for this resource

Comment: I don't want one URL for the whole domain.  I want to map specific URLs on domainA to specific URLs on domainB.

Example:
DomainA.com/1234.asp redirects to DomainB.com/somepage.aspx
DomainA.com/5678.asp redirects to DomainB.com/anotherpage.aspx

In you example:
DomainA.com/1234.asp redirects to DomainB.com/somepage.aspx
DomainA.com/5678.asp redirects to DomainB.com/somepage.aspx

That's not what we're looking for.